# Rest api get call using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I iam trying to consume rest api using jquery ajax, i am facing problem in doing that 
My api is `http://183.11.23/Kapture/Service1.svc/LoginVerification/abc@outlook.com/123`

My Html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>

<script src="login.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<div>
<form onsubmit="login()">
email:<input type="email" name="email" id="emailId"></br>
password:<input type="password" name="password" id="password">
<button type="submit" name="submit" >submit</button>
</form></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My js file is

```
function login(){

    var myusername = $("#emailId").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://183.11.23/Kapture/Service1.svc/LoginVerification/myusername /password",

      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
         $("#resultarea").text(data);
      }
    });
}
```

Please help me

Comment: `183.11.23` - no, that's not the IP-number of your service, it's invalid. Insert the real IP-number and try again.

Comment: Cross domain cannot with jquery, buuuuttt: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506208/jquery-ajax-cross-domain

Comment: Hi @JohannesJander i have not given full url it is dummy for security reason

Comment: @Thomas i have disabled web security, my question is this the right way to pass parameters

Comment: So which problem are you facing? What is your question? What does not work? What would you expect and what actually happens? Which errors do you see? Kindly provide us details.

Comment: @JohannesJander my question is this the right way to consume api for get method, How to pass email and password from html page to js file, i am trying this for first time

Comment: `"http://183.11.23/Kapture/Service1.svc/LoginVerification/myusername /password"` - that's never going to work. You need to read up on how to set arguments on a jQuery GET request: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/ - `data` is what you need to transmit username/password.

Comment: @JohannesJander i am not getting by using this type, can u help me how to pass

Comment: Is the API set in stone or could it also react to `http://183.11.23/Kapture/Service1.svc/LoginVerification?username=abc@outlook.com&password=123` ?

Comment: @JohannesJander api is like this http://183.82:8484/KaptureKountService/Service1.svc/LoginVerification/abc@outlook.com/123.     for this api i will get output as {"LoginVerificationResult":[{"RoleID":1,"UserID":1,"UserName":"Mark"}]}

Comment: Then you need to URL-encode the username and password and add them to the url via string concatenation.

Comment: @JohannesJander ya thats what iam stuck with how to pass the html values to api

Comment: Look, I am not going to write your code for you. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) how to URL-encode the parameters and after that, use the answer below but add the URL-encoded parameters instead of the un-encoded ones

Comment: On a side note WHY is it a GET request if you are sending username and password ? should be a POST

Answer (score 0):

You should update your service to use request parameters in it instead of passing them in a 'username/password' way
You can them pass them as parameters in your url in your function, although this is not the best way, but you haven't posted your service method which  you should for a better approach for this

```
"http://183.11.23/Kapture/Service1.svc/LoginVerification?username=someuser&password=somepassword"
```

Javascript :

```
function login(){

    var myusername = $("#emailId").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "http://183.11.23/Kapture/Service1.svc/LoginVerification?username=" + myusername +"&password="+password,

      cache: false,
      success: function(data){
         $("#resultarea").text(data);
      }
    });
}
```

and on backend you should have something like

```
  String username = Request.Querystring["username"];
  String password = Request.Querystring["password"];
```

Comment: That's a bad way to do it, it will not escape things like `/`

Comment: i dont understand, if the username contains "some/username" wont this be passed as it is through querystring?

Comment: if you set a json value in the data property of the ajax call ... doesnt jQuery encode the key value pairs for you in the url, in case of a GET request that is ?